# Data not persisting using cloudant-sync on android

Tags: android, cloudant

I am currently working on an android project where I would like to store lots of data collected by sensors locally to be able to later push them to my cloudant database for when I do not have access to internet while collecting data.
I am using the git repo https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android

However if the application closes, the data seems to be cleared.

```
DocumentStore ds = DocumentStore.getInstance(new File(path, "my_document_store"));
```

When this line is executed, does it create a new file excluding all my previous data after the app is reopened? Or simply my data is cleared when the app is closed?
Is there a way that the data could persist even when the app is closed?

This is the way I store the data.

```
path = MainActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getDir("documentstores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ds = DocumentStore.getInstance(new File(path, "my_document_store"));
DocumentRevision revision = new DocumentRevision();
revision.setBody(DocumentBodyFactory.create(obj));
```

Where obj is a hash map for this one measurement and has all the data inside.

When the application is closed then reoppened, I cannot seem to find the object that was just saved.

Comment: You're not showing us the right bits of the code. Show the whole segment, how you determine the path, how you write a document to your store. Plenty of examples here: https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/CrudSamples.java

Comment: @xpqz Hi, I have added a piece of my code showing how the objects are saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a call to save the revision to the DocumentStore. That would look something like this:

```
DocumentRevision saved = ds.database().create(revision);
```